Execution failed for task ':flutter_windowmanager:verifyReleaseResources'
in my flutter app, i run it without any problem, but when building APK i get the following problem
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_windowmanager:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:/Users/user/.../..../.../mesu_ahmed/build/flutter_windowmanager/intermediates/merged_res/release/values/values.xml:194: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

how can i solve it without removing flutter window manager

I found a solution : simply downgrade to flutter 3.22.2 and it will work


Please update or remove flutter_windowmanager package


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
